# Jenkins failing to checkout pipeline script when repository contains submodules

Tags: git, jenkins, submodule

I have a Jenkins multibranch pipeline job that was working prior to adding submodules. Now that submodules have been added, the job hangs when trying to checkout the pipeline script from the repository.

Complete log (last line is where it hangs):

```
Started by user [REDACTED]
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to git@gitlab.[REDACTED].git
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.[REDACTED].git # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials [REDACTED]
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/develop
Seen branch in repository origin/production
Seen branch in repository origin/staging
Seen 3 remote branches
Obtained Jenkins/WebGL from 72dd1dcad47cd4dd28110ac21e32c01dc93c86bc
Running in Durability level: PERFORMANCE_OPTIMIZED
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on ci-slave8 in /data/jenkins/workspace/[REDACTED]
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
using credential c442fbdc-7eb4-4a2b-b3f2-bdad07e4cb5b
Cloning the remote Git repository
Using shallow clone
Avoid fetching tags
Cloning repository git@gitlab.[REDACTED].git
 > git init /data/jenkins/workspace/[REDACTED] # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.[REDACTED].git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials [REDACTED]
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress git@gitlab.[REDACTED].git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --depth=1
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.[REDACTED].git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.[REDACTED].git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.[REDACTED].git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials [REDACTED]
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress git@gitlab.[REDACTED].git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --depth=1
Checking out Revision 72dd1dcad47cd4dd28110ac21e32c01dc93c86bc (develop)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 72dd1dcad47cd4dd28110ac21e32c01dc93c86bc
```

Here is a [screen shot of the job configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXnSj.png).

Also upon checking the build machine when the hang occurs I find that the terminal is [prompting for a password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnhNW.png).

From my understanding, the credentials specified in the the first screenshot are what should be used when checking out the pipeline script.

**Is there a special trick for submodules? Or have I configured something incorrectly?**

Comment: Looks like somebody had the same issue as you over on the DevOps site.  Check it out, you might find that one of the answers works for you: https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3895/4115

Comment: @jayhendren Oh hmm the issue with a SSH vs HTTP url for submodules seems like the likely issue, but adding a deploy key (as per the answer in the linked question) doesn't resolve it. :(